# pytest does not pass along environment variables for functional tests from root folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

So, I have my app structured like this:

```
# container.py
class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(modules=[".routes"])
    print(f"$$$$$$$\n testinggggg  - {os.environ.get('ENV')}\n$$$$$$")
    config = providers.Configuration(
        yaml_files=[
            "./src/conf/common.yaml",  # load the common config first
            config_file_path[
                os.environ.get("ENV", "DEV")
            ],  # env specific config - will override values in common.yaml
        ]
    )
    config.load(envs_required=True)
    print(f"$$$$$$$\nconfig  loaded as - {config.get('app')}\n$$$$$$")
    db_repository = providers.Resource(DBRepository, config.get("app.db_repository"))
```

and

```
# __init__.py
def create_app():
    print("@@@@@@ in create_app() @@@@@@@")
    container = Container()
    container.init_resources()

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.container = container

    # connect url rules and register error handlers
    routes.configure(app)
    return app
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
tests
 |--unit_tests
      |-- test_service.py
 |--functional_tests
      |-- test_functional.py
```

My functional test looks like this:

```
import json
import os
from unittest import mock

import pytest
import requests
from flask import url_for

from test.util.mock_db import MockDB

"""
These tests spin up a testing instance of the app and test the APIs end to end
"""


@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def mock_settings_env_vars():
     with mock.patch.dict(
         os.environ,
         {
             "ENV": "TEST",
             "DB_USERNAME": os.environ.get("DB_USERNAME", "root"),
             "DB_PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD", "admin"),
             "DB_HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST", "localhost"),
             "DB_PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT", "3306"),
         },
     ):

         yield


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def app():
    # test if pytest fixture for env vars works as expected
    assert os.environ["ENV"] == "TEST", f"ENV is set to {os.environ['ENV']}"
    print(f"********* HIIIII ********* {os.environ['ENV']}")
    from src import create_app

    mock_db = MockDB(
        os.environ["DB_USERNAME"],
        os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"],
        os.environ["DB_HOST"],
        os.environ["DB_PORT"],
    )
    mock_db.setup()
    app = create_app()
    yield app
    mock_db.teardown()
    app.container.unwire()


def test_check(client, app):
    response = client.get(url_for("check"))
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.data == b"You hit /"
```

I invoke pytest from the command line as:

```
/tests $ pytest -s -rAf
```

When I run this command, so I can just run all tests with a single command - functional & unit - the `create_app()` function does NOT get the environment variables
However, when I run:

```
/tests $ pytest functional_tests/test_functional -s -rAF
```

The test executes successfully.

How/why does this affect the environment variables while running the tests? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to the execution order of the fixtures. `app` fixture seems to rely on what `mock_settings_env_vars` sets up. However, `app` has the `scope` set to `session` and should therefore run before `mock_settings_env_vars` that has the scope set to `module`. The unexpected thing in my opinion is that it actually works when you run `pytest functional_tests/test_functional`.

You could start by checking Pytest's execution plan:

```bash
$ pytest -s -rAf --setup-plan
```

...vs...

```bash
$ pytest -s -rAF --setup-plan functional_tests/test_functional
```

To alter the fixture order, you might make `app` dependent on `mock_settings_env_vars`. However, you would need to alter the scopes. I'm not sure why these two have a different scope but you can try to set them both to `session` or `module`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def mock_settings_env_vars():
    ...

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def app(mock_settings_env_vars):
    ...
```

Comment: I ran the `--setup-plan` and the set-up order looks as expected (with both of the scopes set to session) - I don't know why, when we create a Container, suddenly there's no context of environment variables.

Comment: Another weird peculiar thing I noticed is that, when I do ` $ pytest --ignore=unit_tests/  -s -rAf` -- the rests run perfectly fine! But the moment the unit_tests come into play, the error comes back up again

Comment: @Saturnian I'm afraid the only solution is to debug your code. Set breakpoints in fixtures and tests, run and observe the state of your environment and objects.

Comment: I did :( I really hve no further insights - its a very weird behaviour!!